# Power laptop battery without internal power circuit

Tags: laptop, power-supply, laptop-repair, charging

I have two identical laptops and one of them is broken. I expect it has something to do with the charging circuit. The laptop works fine when it is provided with a full battery. But it doesn't receive power from the adapter.

I've opened the laptop and did some basic measurements with my multi-meter to check if it's not the charging port which is broken.

An motherboard replacement would cost about € 350 which is quite a lot for a 3 year old laptop.

### Question:

1. Would it be possible to buy an external charging circuit and connect it to the battery directly?
2. Could I maybe cut out the battery entirely and provide power to the laptop where the battery normally does this? I'm not sure if this is possible, I expect the laptop to do all kinds of checks to for instance display the current capacity of the battery to the user.
3. Is there still hope for this laptop or should I just buy a new motherboard or entire new laptop ?

The laptop requires an 19V, 4.74A, 90W input. The battery is an Li-ion battery pack which requires an input of 11.1V and has a capacity of 4400 mAh.

Comment: I even have few laptops which are lying around with similar problem, Let's hope somebody on SU can help you.